# Evaluate the limiting value using mean-value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, logarithms

> Prove that
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{n}^{n+ 1}\sin e^{x}{\rm d}x= 0$$

I already have a solution but I want to see a proof(s) using mean-value theorem, it will be travelled ! Now let me show
$$\left | \int_{n}^{n+ 1}\sin e^{x}{\rm d}x \right |= \left | \int_{e^{n}}^{e^{n+ 1}}\frac{\sin x}{x}{\rm d}x \right |\leq\left | \left ( \frac{\cos e^{n}}{e^{n}}- \frac{\cos e^{n+ 1}}{e^{n+ 1}} \right )- \int_{e^{n}}^{e^{n+ 1}}\frac{\cos x}{x^{2}}{\rm d}x \right |\leq$$
$$\leq\left | \frac{\cos e^{n}}{e^{n}}- \frac{\cos e^{n+ 1}}{e^{n+ 1}} \right |+ \int_{e^{n}}^{e^{n+ 1}}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{e^{n+ 1}}+ \frac{1}{e^{n}}+ \frac{1}{e^{n+ 1}}+ \frac{1}{e^{n}}\rightarrow 0\,{\rm as}\,n\rightarrow\infty$$

Comment: haidangel. Just noticed a problem with the answer.$ e^{n+1}-e^n=e^n(e-1)$divide by $e^n$(smallest $t$) you get $\le (e-1)$, not $0!!$

Comment: I would not know where else to apply the MVT. It gives you an upper bound $ \le (e-1)$. Sorry.

Comment: Considering $|\sin y  \int (1/t)dt|$ gives you an upper bound $1$, better than my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVT for integrals:

$|\displaystyle{\int_{e^n}^{e^{n+1}}}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx|=$

$|\dfrac{\sin t}{t}\displaystyle{ \int_{e^n}^{e^{n+1}}}1dx|=|\dfrac{\sin t}{t}(e^{n+1}-e^n)|$

where $t \in [e^n,e^{n+1}].$

Take the limit.

There is a problem here : Taking the limit gives you an upper bound $(e-1)$, not the desired result.